# How to overwrite tier_price.phtml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to change something in file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/tier_prices.phtml

- but I do not know where to save copy of file in my own theme?

Answer (score 1):

Save your **tier_price.phtml** file at below location

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/tier_price.phtml

Comment: I tried but this way its not working.I raised a seprate question on the same : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263473/extend-tier-price-phtml-in-child-theme-of-a-custom-theme-magento-2

can you please see