# Extend tier_price.phtml in child theme of a custom theme Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, phtml, tierprice, template-override

**From:**

> /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml

**To:**

> /app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/tier_price.phtml

I create child theme now want to extend few files but i am stuck.

Flushed cache and added the site in developer mode.

Tried : [How to overwrite tier_price.phtml in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201053/how-to-overwrite-tier-price-phtml-in-magento-2)

**Update Solution: Correct path:**

> app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml

`Command used : sudo rm -rf var/ && sudo rm -rf pub/static && sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && sudo php bin/magento cache:flush && sudo chown www-data:www-data  -R *`

Thank you @chirag-patel and @ylgen-guxholli for your support.

Comment: have you got solution or need some more clearification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you removed generated and static files ?

```
rm -rf generated/*
rm -rf pub/static/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Add the price directory in your override

```
/app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml
```

and see if your theme is generating the static files.

Comment: I am in developer mode, still i executed this , but no changes

Comment: updated my answer , you forgot to add price directory in your override , make the commads i added and it will be ok

Comment: Added that price folder still same issues even after running above all commands again

Comment: is your theme even generated ?

Comment: Yes, generated folder is created again

Comment: i mean your theme not the generated dir.

Comment: My child theme is working. I even extended the one file at this location  : app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: Glad you solved that, anyway i updated my answer with correct path :D

Answer (score 2):

You define wrong at `Magento_Catalog` because core file path is belongs to from `module-configurable-product` module and you write `Magento_Catalog` so no file found **tier_price.phtml** in `Magento_Catalog` core module.

You have to write `Magento_Configurable_Product` insted of `Magento_Catalog`

Try with below way.

> /app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/Magento_Configurable_Product/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml

Remove `/var` & `/generated` folder then run below command.

> php bin/magento c:f
>
> php bin/magento c:c

Comment: I corrected my path in child theme , removed var folder , cleaned cache still no success.

Comment: Finally its done correct path will be app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue_child/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/